# Pascals triangle - undesired output

Tags: java

Given a non-negative integer numRows, generate the first numRows of Pascal's triangle.

In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it.

Example:

```
Input: 5
Output:
[
     [1],
    [1,1],
   [1,2,1],
  [1,3,3,1],
 [1,4,6,4,1]
]
```

[image]

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {

        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> prev = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<>();

        if(numRows<=0)
            return res;

        prev.add(1);
        res.add(prev);
        if(numRows==1)
        return res;

          prev.add(1);
          res.add(prev); 
        if( numRows==2)
         return res;


            int k=3;

            while(k<=numRows)
            {

                Integer[] arr = prev.toArray(new Integer[prev.size()]);
                curr.clear();
                curr.add(1);
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
                {
                    curr.add(arr[i]+arr[i+1]);

                }
                curr.add(1);
                for(int i : curr)
                System.out.print(i+" ");
                System.out.print("\n");
                res.add(curr);
                prev=curr;
                k++;
            }


        return res;
    }
}
```

For n=3, Im getting correct output.
But for n=4

```
Your stdout
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
Your answer
[[1,1],[1,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,3,3,1]]
Expected answer
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1]]
```

For n=5

```
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
Your answer
[[1,1],[1,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
Expected answer
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
```

If you see - STD OUT has correct values - but final results is different on Leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/description/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that in lines like these, where you are adding a list to `res` e.g.:

```
prev.add(1);
res.add(prev);
```

You are adding a reference of `prev` to `res` so if `prev` changes, the changes will be reflected in `res`. For example:

```
    prev.add(1);    // prev = [1]
    res.add(prev);  // res = [[1]] // all good so far
    if(numRows==1)
        return res;

    prev.add(1);    // prev = [1, 1]            
    res.add(prev);  //  res = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]  or [prev, prev] // here's the problem
    if( numRows==2)
        return res;
```

Just create a shallow copy of the list you are trying to insert using `new ArrayList<>(listToCopy);`

```
public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {

    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> prev = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<>();

    if (numRows <= 0)
        return res;

    prev.add(1);
    res.add(new ArrayList<>(prev));
    if (numRows == 1)
        return res;

    prev.add(1);
    res.add(new ArrayList<>(prev));
    if (numRows == 2)
        return res;

    int k = 3;

    while (k <= numRows) {

        Integer[] arr = prev.toArray(new Integer[prev.size()]);
        curr.clear();
        curr.add(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            curr.add(arr[i] + arr[i + 1]);

        }
        curr.add(1);
        for (int i : curr)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");
        res.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
        prev = curr;
        k++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

for `n` = 5, `res`:

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```